# Converting a list with no tuples into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list

Normally when you want to create a turn a set of data into a Data Frame, you make a list for each column, create a dictionary from those lists, then create a data frame from the dictionary.

The data frame I want to create has 75 columns, all with the same number of rows. Defining lists one-by-one isn't going work. Instead I decided to make a single list and iteratively put a certain chunk of each row onto a Data Frame.
Here I will make an example where I turn a list into a data frame:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# Example list

df = 
   a b c d e
0  0 2 4 6 8
1  1 3 5 7 9

# Result I want from the example list
```

Here is my test code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[], 'd':[], 'e':[]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# Here is my test data frame, it contains 5 columns and no rows.

lst = np.arange(10).tolist()

# This is my test list, it looks like this lst = [0, 2, …, 9]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i]\
    .append(pd.Series(lst[2 * i:2 * i + 2]))

# This code is supposed to put two entries per column for the whole data frame.
# For the first column, i = 0, so [2 * (0):2 * (0) + 2] = [0:2]
# df.iloc[:, 0] = lst[0:2], so df.iloc[:, 0] = [0, 1]
# Second column i = 1, so [2 * (1):2 * (1) + 2] = [2:4]
# df.iloc[:, 1] = lst[2:4], so df.iloc[:, 1] = [2, 3]
# This is how the code was supposed to allocate lst to df.
# However it outputs an error.
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

When I add `ignore_index = True` such that I have

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i]\
    .append(pd.Series(lst[2 * i:2 * i + 2]), ignore_index = True)
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

After running the code, I check the results of `df`. The output is the same whether I ignore index or not.

```
In: df
Out:
   a   b   c   d   e
0  0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

It seems that the first loop runs fine, but the error occurs when trying to fill the second column.

Does anybody know how to get this to work? Thank you.

Comment: Please make a fresh example. Show the starting list and the desired DataFrame and no distractions. (The example does not need 75 rows.)

Comment: Thank you @timgeb for your advice. I have implemented it in my latest edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
alst = np.array(lst)
df = pd.DataFrame(alst.reshape(2,-1, order='F'), columns = [*'abcde'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  2  4  6  8
1  1  3  5  7  9
```